# Fiddle site for UI mockup

Tags: website-design, tools, mockup

Are there any "fiddle" like sites for UI mockups?

- http://jsfiddle.net/ for javascript
- http://pythonfiddle.com/ for python
- [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for sql

Some site that lets you make a UI mockup and make it available to anyone.
The site should be:

- free
- no account required: you open the page and the editor is there, ready to start
- easy creation of a sharing link
- the editor should be similar to Balsamiq Mockups

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a tool recommendation. Consider asking this in chat.

Comment: Even with your edits this is still a [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) so isn't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. This is the same for questions requesting good book recommendations, toolkits, software etc. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Comment: I was not looking for a "best" application/site but for one site that match that features, like all "fiddle" sites do. Anyway, I understand your reason.

Answer (score 4):

[Mockflow.com](http://www.mockflow.com) and [Moqups.com](http://www.moqups.com) both offer the ability to share with others and edit in real time. You can also provide read-only access to anyone or export your ui mockup as a .pdf.

Mockflow seems to be more developed and stable, but I personally prefer the user experience of moqups.